# Keras model for vehicle orientation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm new to Keras and TensorFlow. I'm trying to train a convolutional neural network for images classification. I have a large number of vehicle images and I need to get an orientation classification. [Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjh3JyXifjkAhXDb1AKHcVNDaUQFjABegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkilthub.cmu.edu%2Farticles%2FVisual_Classification_of_Coarse_Vehicle_Orientation_using_Histogram_of_Oriented_Gradients_Features%2F6561575%2Ffiles%2F12043934.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2D9F9o3FOKm6E0WE5Qk_jh) is an approach using Histogram of Oriented Gradients (HOG) (I also need the car roof class, for a total of nine classes).

Following is the Python code for my CNN.

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (5, 5), input_shape=(1536, 2048, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    Flatten(),
    # One output network layer with 9 nodes (corresponding to the 9 final classes/orientations)
    Dense(9, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'] 
)

model.fit(
    train_images,                 # Training data
    to_categorical(train_labels), # Training targets
    epochs=4,
    batch_size=16
)
```

As you can see my CNN is made of just three layers. My training dataset is made of a sample of 100 different vehicles, each having all the nine required orientations, for a total of 900 images. With four epochs, I managed to achieve a 90% accuracy in training phase, but only ~50% accuracy in testing phase. This model is not behaving well in predicting results for images that it has never seen before.

My CNN model is very basic. I had to decrease the number of epochs from 5 to 4, because it started to overfit at the fifth epoch. My questions are: how can I improve my model? Is my dataset large enough? Do I have to add more layers to the model?

Thanks in advance.

## Update

Here's the reviewed model:

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),

    Conv2D(64, (3, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),

    Conv2D(128, (3, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),

    Conv2D(128, (3, 3)),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),

    Conv2D(256, (3, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),

    Flatten(),
    # One output network layer with 9 nodes (corresponding to the 9 final classes/orientations)
    Dense(9, activation='softmax')
])
```

Comment: Thia model still too small, train a better model in Colab if you don't have GPU

Answer (score 0):

A large difference between training and test performance is often an indication of overfitting. Since your model is already quite shallow, you could consider changing the number of features calculated in the `Conv2D` layer. How does it perform with 16 or 24 features instead of 32?

Answer (score 0):

## First question:

I'd use a better small model like `MobileNets` or `EfficientNetB0` because your model right now is too small, it wouldn't even work in mnist. But beware not to use too big model because it might easier to overfit in small dataset.

Also, reduce image input size, 224*224 is usually enough, large image lead to overfit in small dataset.

The most important note is do not forget to use data augmentation, like `ImageDataGenerator` in keras.

## Second question:

It's not, I think it will be difficult even with `EfficientNetB0`, at least you might need 50+ images per class for traditional image classifier. As far as I know, `Siamese network` or  `Matching network` might give better result.

## Third question:

Similar to the first, your network is even smaller than the first CNN, `LeNet`, which takes 32x32 input images.

## Update:

Use this instead of just stacking more Conv layers.

```
from keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import MobileNetV2
from keras import layers, models
base_model = MobileNetV2(include_top=False)
x = base_model.output
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax')(x)
model = models.Model(base_model.inputs, x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I reduced the image size, increased my dataset, changed the model and I managed to achieve a testing accuracy of about 80%, not bad. Updated model is in the original question. Problems arise when I added data augmentation (only width and height shifts): here my testing accuracy drops again to 50%. Why could that happen? Should I keep increasing my dataset to achieve better results? Is it worth to review the model again?

Comment: Maybe you shifted too much? If the objects almost fit the images then shifting might cause something lost. Normally I just shift around 0.1-0.15 and use `flip` also.

Comment: More data is always better but I can't tell if it really worth it if you can try something else(matching algorithm). This looks like when we identify whales, which usually only 2-3 imgs per class.

Comment: Just like I said in the very first answer, use already tested model!! It'll difinitely better than just stack more layer if you can use pretrained weights.

Comment: Thanks again for the answers. I tried the MobileNetV2 that you suggested, but unfortunately testing accuracy is about 35% while training accuracy is still very high (about 96%). Any suggestion on how I can improve this model?

Comment: How many images per class you have again? If less than 100 then I suggest `matching network` or `Siamese network` instead of regular classification.

Comment: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_siamese.py

Comment: It's feels like a Facial Recognition task than normal image classification to me.

Comment: And with these network, instead of use 1 images per car for validation(which is not good enough), train of all 10 images of 90 cars and use 10 cars(all 10 images) to validate instead